# On Ubuntu 22.04.2 the Package 'libu2f-udev' seems needed for google-chrome-stable it installs without issue - Why?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, google-chrome, udev

It looks like Google chrome has updated the google-chrome-stable to Version 111.0.5563.64 which depends on libu2f-udev. However, I got the following results during installation:

> Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
> Unpacking google-chrome-stable (111.0.5563.64-1) over (108.0.5359.124-1) ...
> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
> google-chrome-stable depends on libu2f-udev; however:
> Package libu2f-udev is not installed.

> dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

After installation it seems there's no issue running Chrome. Is there really a need for that dependency? I've found that it's related to 2FA. What was left "unconfigured?"

Seeing as my installation of Ubuntu is running as a server I wonder if leaving it unconfigured is wise.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Where can this question be asked for ESM version?

Comment: The only SE site that allows it is SE *Unix & Linux*, ESM does have some *paid* support options which include email, phone & more so refer to Ubuntu sites like my prior links. @SeekTruth but also don't forget some ESM support for Desktop installs was only provided when *deb* packages were replaced with *snap* options as was documented when 16.04 started ESM in the security & other notices.

Comment: excellent question, too bad it is not even allowed to post such a question here.

Comment: As there are still 16.04 LTS running: try this:   <br/>      wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libu2f-host/libu2f-udev_1.1.4-1_all.deb dpkg  <br/>      -i libu2f-udev_1.1.4-1_all.deb <br/>After that, you can install the deb and then retry update Chrome or Vivaldi Browser.